# Iam not able to login to bastion server-permission denied error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bastion-host, bastion

When I login to bastion server every time, there is initial shell script which will run and records sessions.

```
if [[ -z $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND ]]; then

  LOG_FILE="`date --date="today" "+%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"`_`whoami`"
  LOG_DIR="/var/log/ssh-bastion/"

  echo ""
  echo "NOTE: This SSH session will be recorded"
  echo "AUDIT KEY: $LOG_FILE"
  echo ""

  # suffix the log file name with a random string.
  SUFFIX=`mktemp -u _XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`

  script -qf --timing=$LOG_DIR$LOG_FILE$SUFFIX.time $LOG_DIR$LOG_FILE$SUFFIX.data --command=/bin/bash

else
  echo "This bastion supports interactive sessions only. Do not supply a command"
  exit 1

fi
```

Now when I try to login its giving below error

> script: cannot open /var/log/ssh-bastion/2024-03-29_06-52-11_username_m8hI1GxwGYd5847vhanBcn9Www1Koq8X.data: Permission denied

It was working well earlier and I have been facing this issue since 2 days. All my directory permissions are same and there is no change in any file/directory permissions.

Comment: How do you know that "there is no change in any file/directory permissions"? Are you able to login and verify this, or does the script prevent you from logging in? If you can login, then you can debug the shell script by running each command manually. It is giving an error on the `script -qf ...` line.